# jquery append input field and post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.post(
        '/foo.php',{
            name:myform.name.value, 
            interest:myform.interest.value,
            interest2:myform.interest2.value...
        }        
});
```

```
<input type="button" value="Add more interest" />
```

I have a form use jquery post. There is a button can append more input type text.

My questions

1 when user click and append more input field, in side of `$.post(...` how can I add more script, so I can post it to next page?

2 in my php page

```
if(isset($_POST['interest1'], $_POST['interest2']...)){}
```

how can I know how many extra input fields user has added?

3  how can I limit maximum 3 input fields user can append?

Comment: For 2 : You can use the [] syntax in input names : <input name="interest[]">, then $_POST['interest'] will be an array containing all your fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting form fields manually in your post request?
Bad idea, you'd be better of using jQuery's serialize method:

```
$.post("/foo.php", $("#myForm" ).serialize() );
```

For your second question: use array naming on your form elements:

```
<input type="text" name="interest[]">
<input type="text" name="interest[]">
<input type="text" name="interest[]">
<input type="text" name="interest[]">
```

This way you get an array in your post array and can use it like so:

```
foreach ($_POST['interest'] as $interest) {
    doStuff();
}
```

For your third question I'm assuming you wrote a JS method that
adds an input field to the form? If so you could implement
a limit this way:

```
window.formFieldCount = 1;
function addFormField() {
    if (window.formFieldCount >= 3) {
        alert('You can only add three interests!');
        return false;
    }

    // Do your form magic here
    window.formFieldCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**:

```
<form name="some_name">
  <div id="interests">
    <input type="text" name="interests[]" />
  </div>
  <input id="more-interests" type="button" value="Add more interest" />
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maximumNumberOfInterests = 3;
  $('#more-interests').click(function(e){
    if ($("input[name='interests[]']").size() < maximumNumberOfInterests) {
      $('#interests').append('<input type="text" name="interests[]" />');
    } else {
      alert('The maximum number of interests has been reached!');
    }
  });

  $('#submit').click(function(){
    $.post('/foo.php', $('form').serialize());
  });
});
```

**PHP**:

```
if (count($_POST['interests'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['interests'] as $interest) {
    echo $interest;
  }
}
```

[Here is a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5x2zu/) of the HTML/Javascript part

Answer (score 1):

q2. can you change form like this:

static inputs

```
<input name='static[something]'>
<input name='static[somebody]'>
<input name='static[etc]'>
```

and dynamically generated inputs

```
<input name='dynamic[]'>
<input name='dynamic[]'>
<input name='dynamic[]'>
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST['dynamic']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['dynamic'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        /* do some shit with dynamic inputs */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use prepend function before form submit

Like

```
$("#myForm").prepend("<input type=\"text\" name=\"interest"+counter+"\"").submit(function(){
 console.log($("#myForm" ).serializeArray())
 $.post(Event.target.action, $(Event.target).serializeArray(), function(data){
        // your code here
 })
 return false; 
})
```