# Input fields appended with jQuery doesnt submit on POST php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have done it like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724399/267304

But when the form submits the array only consist of first input array value.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<table id="deliveryZipTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="150">Post nr</th>
            <th width="150">Pris</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="newZipDeliveryBox hide">
            <td><input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" value="" placeholder="Fx: 999-2000 eller 2200"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="newd_price[]" value="" placeholder="Pris"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<a class="pointer newZipDelivery">+Add new</a>
```

And the jQuery:

```
    $('.newZipDelivery').click(function(){
        if($('.newZipDeliveryBox').hasClass('hide'))
        {
            $('.newZipDeliveryBox').removeClass('hide');
        }else{
            var $clone = $('.newZipDeliveryBox').clone();
            $clone.removeClass('newZipDeliveryBox');

            $('#deliveryZipTable > tbody > tr:last').after($clone);
        }
    });
```

What the script does is that first time it shows the  (remove class 'hide') and if you press add new again, it clones and appends.

It seems like the cloned tr with the inputs inside that gets appended, doesnt come on the form submit. Any solution?

if i in my html have multiple:

```
<input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" value="" placeholder="Fx: 999-2000 eller 2200">
<input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" value="" placeholder="Fx: 999-2000 eller 2200">
<input type="text" name="newd_zipcode[]" value="" placeholder="Fx: 999-2000 eller 2200">
```

all these submits fine.

**So its only when cloning and appending the input fields, the data doesnt send with POST on submission. Any help?**

Comment: Can you explain what result you are trying to achieve? Your code is setup up to do either A or B, depending on the class of the element, yet you seem to be expecting it to do A and B.

Comment: I am trying to archieve two arrays in the POST data. One named newd_zipcode and one named newd_price. Each array should have entries the value of the input fields. It's pretty simple and used to work, now I just dont know why it wont this time

Comment: IS the problem that the new tr doesn't render in the page, or that the data doesn't appear in the array in the POST submission?

Comment: The data doesnt appear in the array in the POST submission.